# Facing issue with Thymleaf integration with Spring boot version 3

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Please refer to source code from github repo
https://github.com/vishalmestri/SpringSecurity/tree/master/spring-security-ldap-with-db-authorization-master-mysql

I am trying to create POC where authentication will be done from LDAP and authroization will be done from mysql db.

Application is starting , authenticating , authorizing. But when it tries to render thymleaf view, it is throwing exception.

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateOutputException: An error happened during template rendering

I have put exception log in repository.
https://github.com/vishalmestri/SpringSecurity/blob/master/spring-security-ldap-with-db-authorization-master-mysql/exception%20faced.txt

Code tried is given above in github repo.
I am using spring boot 3.0.4 version.

Comment: The say: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#httpServletRequest.remoteUser"  >>> Property or field 'remoteUser' cannot be found on null

Comment: Same code with minor version difference worked successfully with spring boot version 2.x . Please refer to repository https://github.com/vishalmestri/SpringSecurity/tree/master/spring-security-ldap-with-db-authorization-master.  Is there any change in new version of spring boot 3.x which I may be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot 3 comes with Thymeleaf 3.1 which no longer supports `#httpServerRequest`, see https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf31whatsnew.html

The recommended way to do this is to create a dedicated model attribute for what you need. Add this to your controller:

```
@ModelAttribute("remoteUser")
public Object remoteUser(final HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request.getRemoteUser();
}
```

Then you can use `${remoteUser}` in your template.

Comment: In my thymeleaf html page I put this and it worked. <h3 th:inline="text">username: <span th:text="${remoteUser}"></span></h3>